# Python - Regex no group is found

Tags: python, regex

How do I add a group to my regex?

Here is my regex: `(?<=code )(\d+)`

Here is my code:

```
rsize= re.compile(r'(?<=code )(\d+)')
code = rsize.search(codeblock).group("code")
```

How come when I run the code I get the error: `IndexError: no such group` ? How do I write this regex to create a group named `code`?

**EDIT**
I read the responses, but, my question is, how exactly do I append that to my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["named group" syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) is a little bit different:

```
(?P<name>group)
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = "1234 extract the numbers"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<code>\d+)')
>>> pattern.search(s).group("code")
'1234'
```

Comment: A top of this, I tried inserting it into my regex, but failed. What's wrong? I want to get just the ip after the word IP -- Link: http://goo.gl/x5GQzg (Pythex)

Comment: @Farrell32 could you show your input string and the code you have so far? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A named group in [Python's `re` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) is defined as `(?P<name>...)` where `name` is the name of the group and `...` is the pattern the group matches.

So if your goal is to create a named group 'code' that matches a set of digits, you'd want:

```
(?P<code>\d+)
```